# What is a "brake"?

Tags: meaning

In his classic novel ["Sons and Lovers"](https://books.google.com/books?id=qzhkBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA72) D.H. Lawrence wrote:

> Mrs. Morel loved her marketing. In the tiny market-place on the top of the hill, where four roads, from Nottingham and Derby, Ilkeston and Mansfield, meet, many stalls were erected. **Brakes** ran in from surrounding villages. The market-place was full of women, the streets packed with men.

What does the word "brake" mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting-brake#Etymology_and_historic_examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it refers to:

***[Brake](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/brake)***:

> (Horse Training, Riding & Manège) an open four-wheeled horse-drawn carriage. Also spelt: break

(Collins Dictionary )

[image]

(aliceausten.org)